# DB2 Partition and Queue Replication

Tags: db2

The version of DB2 is `v11.1`. This question is with respect to DB2 Queue Replication and dropping of partitions. 
Scenario is that there are 2 tables. `Tab1` is partitioned and `Tab2` is not partitioned. There is queue `DB2` replication setup between `Tab1` and `Tab2` to replicate deletes. Question is that if we do a drop partition on `Tab1` will it replicate the delete of the rows to `Tab2`. 
For e.g. There are 10 rows available in partition1 on `Tab1`. The same 10 rows are present in `Tab2` due to replication.

When a drop partition is triggered on Tab1, will the 10 rows from Tab2 get deleted too?
If we have to achieve the effect, can we implement a custom solution?

Answer (score 0):

Q-rep won't turn a drop partition into deletes.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTRGZ_10.2.1/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.db.repl.sqlrepl.doc/topics/iiyrscapparttblv97fp2.html?cp=SSEPGG_11.1.0

> The DETACH operation is not replicated. The data that is deleted from the source table by the DETACH operation is not deleted from the target table. If you need to change the target data partition into a separate table, you need to do so manually.

The operation is also explicitly excluded in schema level subscriptions.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_10.2.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.repl.qrepl.doc/topics/iiyrqsubcrtschemasub.html

I guess your options are to delete all the rows on the source partition and so only drop empty partitions, or to manually delete the rows on the target when you do the DROP PARTITION.

You could MDC the source tables to speed source deletes, but then again, not sure Q-rep would work with a MDC block delete on the source but a non MDC target. Is your target row organised and hence the partition difference?